# How can I use regex replacement in javascript to find the longest sequence of matching characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

The question posed was:
Given an integer 0 < N < 1000000000000 return the highest number of consecutive digits in the number.
For example in the number 9934445666644 the answer would be 4 because there are:

```
2x 9
1x 3
3x 4
1x 5
4x 6
2x 4
```

In the number provided.
I know I can solve the problem with some counters and loops but thought it would be best to use regex to solve this.

And if the question was extended to highest number of consecutive characters in any string (not limited to digits) how would I do it?

Comment: `console.log((Math.max.apply(Math, "9934445666644".match(/(\d)\1*/g))+"").length);`

Comment: consecutive or not?

Comment: The question posed by whom? Why did you think regexp would be a good solution? *And if the question was extended* So are you, or are you not, including this in the question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - you should post your comment as the answer it is absolutely flawless.

Please post it as the answer, you deserve up votes since your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Posted with explanations, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract all chunks of consecutive identical characters (here, we may just match digits) and then find the longest match.

The regex looks rather basic:

```
/(\d)\1*/g
```

It will match and capture into Group 1 a digit (see `(\d)`) and then zero or more (due to `*` quantifier) values captured in  Group 1.

That means it will match chunks consisting of one digit that will be helpful if there are no repeated digits in the string.

The code will look like

```
console.log((Math.max.apply(Math, "9934445666644".match(/(\d)\1*/g))+"").length);
```

Comment: Thanks. I learnt two things here, backreferencing and that match returns a list of matching strings. Very awesome will be very useful in future.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first bit of the problem is counting the number of repeated digits in your provided number.
We can use javascript's string replace function which allows us to specify a regex pattern to replace and allows us to pass a function to apply some logic based on the matching groups.

```
// The input value, perhaps from reading file...
var inputNumber = readline(); // "9934445666644"

// The input being a string we can use the replace function on it.
var repeatCount = inputNumber.replace(
                 /(0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)/g,
                 function(x){return x.length+" "}); // "2 1 3 1 4 2"
// convert the count string to an array of 
var counts = repeatCount.split(" "); //  [2,1,3,1,4,2]

// Return the maximum number in the counts array.
var highestCount = Math.max.apply(Math, counts); // 4
```

There is probably a better way to do this but this was the best I could come up with my limited knowledge of regex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex is very useful here. What i would do is just iterate over the decimal representation string of the number once:

```js
let N = 9934445666644;
let str = N.toString();
let currentHighest = 1;
let totalHighest = 1;
let lastDigit = str[0];
//not needed, but shows which digit it was
//that occurred so often
let highestDigit = str[0];

for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] === lastDigit) currentHighest++;
  else {
    currentHighest = 1;
    lastDigit = str[i];
  }
  if (currentHighest > totalHighest) {
    totalHighest = currentHighest;
    highestDigit = str[i];
  }
}

console.log(`${highestDigit} occurs ${totalHighest} times in a row.`);
```

If you really need to use regex, it should be solvable by a single regex due to the amount of digits being limited. The resulting regex should be terribly ugly though.

In other words, i think your idea of "it would be best to use regex to solve this" is incorrect and "some counters and loops" is the way to go.

Comment: someone commented this as the answer:
console.log((Math.max.apply(Math, "9934445666644".match(/(.)\1*/g))+"").length)
And it is absolutely flawless, so regex is very useful here.

Comment: @IgnitiousNites if you ask me, that line's readability is questionable and it uses more resources than above solution (iteration in a quick-and-dirty test seemed to be 10-25 times faster for given input, depending on browser).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with splitted numbers.

```js
function getCount(n) {
    return (n).toString().split('').reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (r.last === a) {
            r.max = Math.max(++r.count, r.max);
        } else {
            r.last = a;
            r.count = 1;
        }
        return r;
    }, { last: '', count: 0, max: 0 }).max;
}

console.log(getCount(9934445666644));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `for` loop, set property name of an array to number, increment property value if object property name is matched at nested `for` loop which iterates from current index + 1 until end of input.

Return array having first element set to index of beginning of the greatest sequence of matching characters at original string, second element set to end of sequence length of greatest sequence of matching characters.

`.slice()` or `for` loop can be utilized to retrieve the characters of the greatest matching sequence;

```js
let values = ["9934445666644"
              , Array.from("993444564666644")
              , "aaBBBCCCdd333*******11111"];

// `input`: string, array
function greatestSequence(input) {
  for (var i = 0, res = []; i < input.length; i++) {
    var curr = input[i]; res[i] = 1; 
    for (var j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
      if (curr == input[j]) {
        res[j] = ++res[i];
      } else {
        break
      }
    }
  }
  var g = res.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a < b ? b : a
  });
  var index = res.indexOf(g);
  return [index, index + g];
}

let g0 = greatestSequence(values[0]);
console.log("value[0] indexes:", g0, "values:", values[0].slice(g0[0], g0[1]));

let g1 = greatestSequence(values[1]);

for (var i = g1[0], garr = []; i < g1[1]; garr.push(values[1][i]), i++);
console.log("value[1] indexes:", g1, "values:", garr.join(""));

let g2 = greatestSequence(values[2]);
console.log("value[2] indexes:", g2, "values:", values[2].slice(g2[0], g2[1]));
```

Comment: While this gives the right answer a was looking to see how regex can be used to get to the answer.

Comment: Is Answer not helpful?